# How to re-install OS to a blank SSD?

Tags: macos, recovery

I got myself into a little problem.

I removed macOS from the Mac’s SSD and after trying <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to enter Recovery Mode it just offers Internet Recovery.  Unfortunately, I have no access to the Internet at the moment.

I have a bootable hard drive with macOS Mojave on it but I can’t seem to get the MacBook to boot from it.

I tried holding <kbd>Option</kbd> at boot,  but it doesn’t offer the hard drive as a bootable drive.

How can I get macOS reinstalled on my Mac?

Comment: Well, you are suppose to hold down "alt/option" key instead of the "command" key. Is your Mac compatible with Mojave? Maybe you could edit your question and include the model/year of your Mac.

Comment: Hi David thank you for your quick reply, I meant to say the “alt/option “ key sorry it just puts you to the internet recovery

Comment: If it doesn't offer the HD you have as a boot option, that means the Mac thinks it isn't bootable. You may need to find another Mac and create a bootable installer. If you don't have a friend with one and are near an Apple store I have heard they will help you create a bootable installer (Other folks here may know about this or know otherwise).